# Why doesn't this Facebook Graph API endpoint require an API key?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Why does this URL/endpoint work without any credentials? I can't find any information on it on the Facebook Developer documentation. Is it safe to use for a production application? Does anyone know what the limits are on it?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=https://stackoverflow.com/&fields=og_object%7Bengagement%7D
```

Comment: It's documented at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/using-objects/.

Comment: @ceejayoz I don't think I'm seeing how your link relates to my question. The link you shared is for opengraph, which I don't believe my question has anything to do with(?)

Comment: Your URL is the open graph endpoint. "The response from this endpoint will be a JSON object that contains all the information about the object that was scraped (the same data returned when the Object ID is read from the Graph API)." A `POST` to it triggers a scrape. A `GET` returns the cached data.

Comment: Found the GET docs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v4.0/url

Comment: Thank you! That makes more sense.

Comment: It says there though, _“Any access token can be used to make this request”_ - and any doesn’t usually mean “or none at all”. And trying the request URL mentioned in the question, I currently get an error saying, _“Application request limit reached”_ - so even _if_ this works without an access token still, I would not recommend to use it that way - unless you don’t mind running into that error from time to time.

Comment: And the request as shown does not specify an API version - which usually means it should fall back to the lowest currently available version, but that does not seem to be the case here. But once you explicitly specify it, a token seems required once you go with v2.3 or higher (`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/?id=…`), then it says _“An access token is required to request this resource.”_